# approving application in marketplace that reloads data instead of tombstoning it

Tags: windows-phone-7

I have an application in which i have listboxes,textboxes, etc. I load data in `OnNavigatedTo` so when i come from tombstoning, my data is reloaded.

Is this a problem in app submission? Must i necesarally save the state of the app or is it correct to reload the data (i reload from my database) ?

What is actually tested in the application submission process? The app itself or is my code actually verified?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How you reload your apps state will not affect certification. Your app will go through some automated testing and will be checked for calls to unmanaged code etc. but the actual code/logic will only be tested against the [Windows Phone 7 Certification Requirements](http://go.microsoft.com/?linkid=9730558&ei=IfvETu6iAYeg4gSv2ZzDDQ&usg=AFQjCNGGlTBYdCFwPlIaMQRA2tu5TjFY2w).

Comment: so if i reload my data manually and not save and reload the data it's ok to submit. Thanks! :) i was just looking thought the certification Requirements but it wasn't clear to me: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh184840(v=VS.92).aspx

Comment: You just need to make sure it loads in a reasonable amount of time.

Comment: Thanks for the re-confirmation :)